# HTTP/HTTPS content authentication

Tags: http, authentication, https, proxy

I could find any quick answer on google. Most probably the answer lies somewhere in RFC docs on http or https however I just couldn't (too time consuming ) get those information.
So here is the question:
Is the content of a webpage served through HTTP signed digitally by the server ? Same question for HTTPS.
If yes, how does it work correctly when using a proxy ? In my opinion the proxy could tamper the data, sign the tampered data with it's own private key, and claim that the corresponding proxy's public key is actually the genuine public key of the original server ? I am assuming that the client can't check the original server's public key, because there is a proxy which could lie.
I am sorry if this is a dump question and easy searchable on the internet, but every answer I found posed some doubts to me.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content sent via HTTPS is encrypted, clients verify the authenticity of the host certificates with whom they are communicating. The server uses a TLS/SSL key/certificate which is signed by certificate authorities (CA) The CAs make sure that they only sign the certificates of the rightful owners of a domain. The certificates of the CAs them-self are installed in you browser/OS. By using these pre-installed certificates, the browser can check if the key used by the remote server is signed by a trusted CA.

A man-in-the-middle does not have the original key, nor another key signed by a CA for the domain in question. Therefore, a man-in-the-middle cannot modify the content without breaking HTTPS.

On the other hand, if you want to use a proxy to cache requests, the proxy can terminate the HTTPS connections. This means the proxy has its own connection to the server and verifies the certificates. In order to secure the connection to the client, the proxy acts as a CA and uses a HTTPS connection with self-signed certificates. To avoid that your browser complains about an insecure connection, you need to install the proxies own CA certificate.

---

HTTP content is not signed and can be tampered with.

---

**Edit 2018-06-15:**
I wasn't really precise with the term "signed" here. The server does not actually sign the content it sends. This means if you store the responses from the server, you cannot prove that they came from that server, in other words: [standard TLS dose not provide non-repudiation](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103651/156739). However, the authenticity of the server is established during the handshake. The client encrypts a master-key with the servers public key. Only servers in possession of the private key can decrypt the master-key and derive session keys from them.

CAs, on the other hand, actually sign the certificates. A CA cannot validly deny that it signed for the authenticity of a server certificate.